# Activecell.Adress is not returning to the original field

Tags: vba, excel

I know the inbeded do until works fine but when I set the activecell.address then attempt to return to it I am not taken to the original location.

```
Sub Refresh()
Dim PN
Dim Supervisor
Dim Location

Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Range("A2").Activate

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

PN = ActiveCell.Value
Location = ActiveCell.Address

Worksheets("sheet4").Activate
Range("C2").Activate
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
If PN = ActiveCell.Value Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Select
Supervisor = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -18).Select
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Range(Location).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Supervisor
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Select

Range(Location).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Note it is not an infanate loop it does end but it goes over the information too many times and when i do return to the activecell its anywhere on the sheet.

Comment: It's hard to follow what you are doing. You should learn how to indent your code. I suspect your problem is that `Range(Location).Activate` does not specify a sheet.

Comment: And you can do without all those Selects and Activates.

Comment: Thanks, im not really a programmer, i am just picking up this project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
Sub Refresh()

Dim PN
Dim Supervisor
Dim Location
Dim r As Range
Dim r1 As Range

Set r = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2")

Do Until IsEmpty(r)
    PN = r.Value
    Location = r.Address
    Set r1 = Worksheets("sheet4").Range("C2")
    Do Until IsEmpty(r1)
        If PN = r1.Value Then
            Supervisor = r1.Offset(0, 18).Value
        End If
        Set r1 = r1.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    r.Offset(0, 5).Value = Supervisor
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "Range(Location).Activate" in your code use "Range(Location).select". Remaining code will work as per your logic